# What numbers to look for investment returns

Tags: investing, rate-of-return, ipo

I'm exploring the field of investments and would like to know roughly what numbers and estimates have to be looked at for a company that is going to become public soon. For instance, if I buy 10% of the shares as soon as the company goes public, what number does indicate my return after 10 years? Do I have to estimate the share price based on revenues?

Comment: If the company only offers 10% of the shares, are you going to try to buy all those shares that may well cost you a great deal to acquire them all?

Comment: Hi JB King, no they are issuing 100% of shares and I'm looking into estimates of hypothecially 10%. I think the max cap is set at 15%.

Answer (score 1):

(Value of shares+Dividends received)/(Initial investment) would be the typical formula though this is more of a percentage where 1 would indicate that you broke even, assuming no inflation to be factored.

No, you don't have to estimate the share price based on revenues as I would question how well did anyone estimate what kind of revenues Facebook, Apple, or Google have had and will have.

---

To estimate the value of shares, I'd likely consider what does my investment strategy use as metrics: Is it discounted cash flow, is it based on earnings, is it something else? There are many ways to determine what a stock "should be worth" that depending on what you want to believe there are more than a few ways one could go.

Comment: How would you try to estimate the value of shares? there are so many drivers for it